# How to add a single quote to the text within uib-popover-html Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was trying to add a single quote to the popup text.
Say, I want the text to appear as :

```
Text 'line' 1.
Text 'line' 2.
```

I tried escaping single quotes, using special html character, but in all cases, the hover/tooltip stopped working.

The below code works because it doesn't have single quotes in the text.

```
<a uib-popover-html="'<p>Text line 1.</p>
<p>Text line 2.</p>'"
popover-title="Name your drivers"
popover-trigger="'mouseenter click'">
Hover Here
</a>
```

No much luck even after googling.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: maybe make use of `uib-popover-template` ?

Comment: escaping the single quotes works [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/e5O4KXpWJDCmiQj8QOU2?p=preview).. not sure how you are trying

Comment: Thanks @tanmay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use **uib-popover-template** instead of uib-popover-html :

```
<a uib-popover-template="'popover.html'" 
popover-title="Name your drivers"
popover-trigger="'mouseenter click'">
Hover Here
</a>
```

And the ***popover.html*** file looks like this :

```
<p>Text 'line' 1.</p>
<p>Text 'line' 2.</p>
```

This worked for me :)

http://embed.plnkr.co/4YTnxnV0CSsiVV4uSh9V/